# How to downgrade a specfic package using Pacman

Tags: linux, pacman-package-manager

How is it possible to downgrade a package version using Pacman in Arch distributions?
for example, python-flask is version 2. But I need to downgrade it to 1.1.2-4.

How Can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arch mirrors do not usually maintain older versions of packages, so you cannot directly find older versions in a mirror.

You can look in the Archlinux Archive here for the package: https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/p/python/

Download the package and install it with `pacman -U`

For more information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_Linux_Archive